# Reformat MySQL date with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select data from a MySQL database and show it in a table, which is working so far, but I have a problem with the date format.

I want to reformat the MySQL Date to dd/mm/YY but I don't know how to do it because I don't specifically select the date column. I just select all columns from the table.

Code:

```
<?php
echo "<table style='border: solid 1px black;'>";
echo "<tr><th>Id</th><th>Name</th><th>Date</th></tr>";

class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator { 
     function __construct($it) { 
         parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY); 
     }

     function current() {
         return "<td style='width: 150px; border: 1px solid black;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
     }

     function beginChildren() { 
         echo "<tr>"; 
     } 

     function endChildren() { 
         echo "</tr>" . "\n";
     } 
} 

$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

try {
     $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username,     $password);
     $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users"); 
     $stmt->execute();

     $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

     foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) { 
         echo $v;
     }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: In other programming languages (like c# and java) we can get the column type. I think it is also possible in php. And by knowing column type you can decide how to display it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just in case my assumption of `$k` being the column and `$v` being the value is correct, then this should work:

```
 foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) { 
 switch ($k) {
      case '{{column_name}}':
            // Format {{column_name}} as you like, e.g:
            $date_time = strtotime($v);
            print date("d-m-y", $date_time);
            break;
      default:
            echo $v;
            break;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! But I have the problem that I can't convert the date. The output is always 01.01.1970 if I use $v.

Comment: @Uwe oops, my bad, simply make `d-m-Y` => `d-m-y`. I've updated the answer too.

Comment: Sorry for replying this late. Tanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it that $k is the column name and $v is the value?

If yes, then you can easily detect the date column values and format them:

```
 foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) { 
     switch ($k) {
          case 'date_column':
                // echo formatted $v
                break;
          default:
                echo $v;
                break;
     }
 }
```